# Is this possible with linear backgrounds?

Tags: html, css, background

[image: statistic]

I need to do this statistic which shows 2 aggregated values. It shows the total values of each months. I have done this in bootstrap. Each month is a column with a div inside it with a certain height, depending on the percentage of this value.

This works great, but I dont have an idea, how i get the two black lines of the values to go up like this in a linear way. What i have now looks like this:

[image]

I thought I could do it with linear backgrounds for the div but I cant seem to find a way. What I would need is a left starting point and a right ending point in pixels for the green, the first black line, the second green and the second black line. Is there a way to achieve this or is there a better way?

Comment: you mean a linear background to achieve the whole thing or each month individually?

Comment: each month individually

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with multiple background and CSS variables

```css
.box {
   --p1_start:20px;
   --p1_end:80px;
   
   --p2_start:80px;
   --p2_end:120px;
   border:1px solid;
   height:200px;
   width:150px;
   display:inline-block;
   background:
     /**/
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent calc(50% - 5px),#000 calc(50% - 4px) calc(50% - 1px), green 50%)
       bottom var(--p1_start) left 0/110% calc(var(--p1_end) - var(--p1_start)),  
     linear-gradient(green 0 0) 
       bottom/100% var(--p1_start),
     /**/
     /**/
     linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent calc(50% - 5px),#000 calc(50% - 4px) calc(50% - 1px), red 50%)
       bottom var(--p2_start) left 0/110% calc(var(--p2_end) - var(--p2_start)),  
     linear-gradient(red 0 0) 
       bottom/100% var(--p2_start);
     /**/
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--p1_start:80px;--p1_end:100px;--p2_start:120px;--p2_end:200px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to work pretty nice. I need to check how it can handle when the value is decreasing from one month to another. Then this does not seem to work.

Comment: @flownie it doesn't work for decreasing value, only increasing one. I made a simple demo. I will edit to also consider decreasing values